# If I can't ask questions about electronic devices on Superuser.com, where should I?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

First of all, I don't really understand why that would exclude mobile devices. They ARE computer software and hardware.

Secondly, since none of the admins who closed my ticket gave any helpful information as to why this is or where to go to post my question, maybe someone can tell me where I might be able to do this?

Comment: Please see my answer. I have migrated the question for you so please don't double post.

Comment: Thanks Diago, I have 15 rep now so I upvoted your answer.

Comment: [Should Tablet Computer questions be allowed on Super User?](https://meta.superuser.comhttps://meta.superuser.com/a/3268/301042) on Super User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to point out [what the question you're referring to is](https://superuser.com/questions/238163/how-can-i-prevent-my-google-g-1-from-using-any-kind-of-internet). In this scenario, your specific question is about an Android, so I would suggest you try it on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

In a general scenario, we don't have a specific site for general electronic devices. [The one proposal became unviable](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/) due to the breadth and lack of intersection. Instead, check out the [site listing at stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to find the site that most closely seems to address the device you need to ask about. If one doesn't exist, it may well be that we just don't have a site for it, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think a general site for electronics would be necessary. Thanks for posting the android enthusiasts site. I will use that from now on.

Comment: I think site about electronics is necessary i would like to be able to ask questions about my iphone when it breaks and similar questions. Its really difficult to google the answers online (since there is so many iphone versions)

Answer (score 4):

Since the question was closed by the community and not a diamond moderator, it never got a chance to be migrated. Diamond moderators can migrate questions to sites outside of the normal scope, and I have done so with this question and you can find it [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/how-can-i-prevent-my-google-g-1-from-using-any-kind-of-internet)

The Super User mobile policy have been in place pretty much since it launched, and has been debated many times in meta. However these devices are off topic, and when relevant questions will be migrate to another Stack Exchange site if one exists.

For future reference. Flag the question for moderator attention and indicate which site you would like it migrated too, and it will be done.

Comment: I was breezing through your Meta, admittedly more unfamiliar with it than I am with here. I found a lot of statements of the absoluteness of the policy, but I never found any statement of what led to the policy being put in place. I assume it's basically the same reason as the policy against video games and consoles?

Comment: Thanks Diago. I will upvote this once I have 15 rep.

Comment: @Grace. Correct. It was decided during Beta if I recall, since we got a huge amount of iPhone questions at the time.